# Why does AspectRatio not work in a ListView?

Tags: flutter

Why does AspectRatio not preserve my aspect ratio when it is placed in a ListView?

#### Unexpected behaviour (doesn't preserve aspect ratio in a ListView)

```
return ListView(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 200,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1 / 2,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

#### Expected behaviour (works outside of a ListView)

```
return Container(
  height: 200,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1 / 2,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because "[in the cross axis, the children are required to fill the ListView.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)" So the ListView stretches the Container.

The solution will be to wrap the Container in a Center widget which helps maintain the child widget size "[in case the parent widget has its own opinions regarding the size that the Container should take"](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html#widgets.Container.1) like below:

```
 Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1 / 2,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
    )
```

Comment: That is great, I thought AspectRatio should have overridden the value but that works.  Great answer :-)